# Convergence of series an if $f(a_n)$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I'm trying to prove the following:

$f$ is differentiable at $0$ so that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0) \neq 0$. Also the series $\{a_n\}$ is positive for all $n$ and $\{a_n\}\to 0$
.
Prove that $$\sum f(a_n) \text{ converges }\iff\sum a_n \text{ converges.}$$

The $\Leftarrow$ part was pretty easy, i'm stuck at the $\Rightarrow$ part.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of the inverse function theorem?

Comment: How can we use the inverse function theorem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. By the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one has
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+o\left(x\right)
$$ giving
$$
f(x)=f'(0)x+o\left(x\right)
$$ and, using  that $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, one may find a $n_0$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=n_0}^Nf(a_n)=f'(0)\sum_{n=n_0}^Na_n+\sum_{n=n_0}^N o\left(a_n\right)
$$ Then one may conclude with the comparison test using $f'(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Regarding the comparison test, we don't know if f'(0) or f(an) are positive or not. Can we take an absolute value here? And then an will absolutely converge.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$f(a_n)=f(0)+f'(0)a_n+o(1)a_n=a_n(f'(0)+o(1))$$

using [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) with the Peano form of the remainder.

Hence, we see that

$$\sum f(a_n)= \sum a_n(f'(0)+o(1))$$

and

$$\sum a_n =\sum \frac{f(a_n)}{f'(0)+o(1)}$$

Comment: When you write o(1), do you mean the Lagrange remainder?

Comment: Not Lagrange; Peano.  [SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable)